# How to swipe through tabs on button click

Tags: android, button, tabs, swipe

How do you swipe through Tabs on a button click event?

i.e if a calculate Button is pressed then the user will be moved to another page on the tabbed Activity that gives them their result.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements   
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager mViewPager;

//TODO: Find alternatives to deprecated methods
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }
}

public void onClick(View view){
    EditText weight_entry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_entry);
    EditText height_entry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_entry);
    String weight = weight_entry.getText().toString();
    String height = height_entry.getText().toString();
    TextView calc_label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calc_label);

    if (weight.matches("")|| height.matches("")){
        return;
    } else {
        float t;
        float w = Float.parseFloat(weight);
        float h = Float.parseFloat(height);

        //TODO: check this
        t = (float)((double)Math.round(10D * (double)(w / (h * h))) / 10D);

        calc_label.setText("Your BMI is: " + Float.toString(t));
    }


    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(weight_entry.getWindowToken(), 0);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(height_entry.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new InputFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ResultFragment();
            case 2:
                return new HistoryFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post some of your code?

Anyway, try doing:

`mTabHost.setCurrentTab(idx);`

**UPDATE:**

Ok, apparently you have a ViewPager, not a Tab ;)

Try this on your `onClick` `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(idx);`

Been idx, the index of the page you want to show. I guess in your case would be 1.

Comment: Ok, apparently you have a ViewPager, not a Tab ;)

Try this
`mViewPager.setCurrentItem(idx);`

Been idx, the index of the page you want to show. I guess in your case would be `1`

On your onClick.